# Usar filter en Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Tengo mi función `buscar`, pero me sale este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí le dejo el código:

view.py

```
class ListarTipoAlmacen(ListView):
    model = Tipo_almacen
    template_name = 'tipo_almacen/lista_tipo_almacen.html'
    paginate_by = 10

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        buscar_descripcion = request.GET.get('buscar_descripcion', '')

        lista_tipo_almacen = Tipo_almacen.objects.filter(descripcion__contains=buscar_descripcion)

        if buscar_descripcion == '':
            context['error'] = 'ingrese dato por favor'
        else:
            if not buscar_descripcion:
                context['error'] = 'el dato ingreso no existe'

        return render_to_response('tipo_almacen/lista_tipo_almacen.html', {'lista_tipo_almacen': lista_tipo_almacen}, context['error'])


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListarTipoAlmacen, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        lista_tipo_almacen = Tipo_almacen.objects.all().order_by('descripcion')

        paginator = Paginator(lista_tipo_almacen, self.paginate_by)
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            pagina = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            pagina = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            pagina = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context['lista_tipo_almacen'] = pagina
        return context
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder="ingrese nombre" class="form-control input-md" type="text">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>


    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4>Lista de Tipo de almacen</h4>
        </div>

        <table class="table">
            <th>Nombres</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
            <tbody>
                {% for data in lista_tipo_almacen %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            {{data.descripcion}}
                        <td>

                            <a href="{% url 'editar_tipo_almacen' data.pk %}">Editar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
                            <a href="{% url 'eliminar-tipo-almacen' data.pk %}" data-toggle="modal_almacen" data-target="#modal_almacen" data-id="{{ data.descripcion }}">Eliminar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Andres, ¿cuál es el problema?

Comment: Eso es cuestión del frontend, no de Django y no indicas si utilizas algún framework en el frontend o qué has intentado.

Comment: estas es mi funcion buscar 

buscar = Tipo_almacen.objects.filter(descripcion='')


mi dudas es como paso esaese buscra mi html

Comment: Has leido algo sobre ajax y django? Esto te puede servir como base [Django real python](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-and-ajax-form-submissions/) y [Django y ajax](http://pythoniza.me/ajax-en-django-con-jquery/)

Comment: Una vez más, usa django-haystack, te hace casi todo el trabajo, tu nada más creas la vista y sale.

Comment: SImplemente no existe la variable `context` en la función `get`. Intenta inicializándola usando algo como `context = self.get_context_data()` o simplemente define uno nuevo `context = {}`

Comment: Andres, si tienes estos problemas creo que antes de continuar con Django deberías primero leer algunos libros o tutoriales sobre Python puro sino es probable que sigas topándote con cosas asi.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es usar el método `get` y allí filtrar la información para luego pasarla al template.

Un ejemplo:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    name_search = request.GET.get('name_search', '')
    if not name:
        raise Http404

    lista_tipo_almacen = Tipo_almacen.objects.filter(
        descripcion__contains=name_search,
    )
    return render_to_response(
        'store_search.html',
        {
            'lista_tipo_almacen': lista_tipo_almacen,
        }
    )
```

Comment: dime como lo paso en mi template en mi html, podrias ayudarem con eso por favor

Comment: con render_to_response haces eso.

Comment: Estoy usando render_to_response pero me sale un error e puesto como esta mi codigo actulamente @Felipe Zuluaga

Comment: Hazlo así: return render_to_response('tipo_almacen/lista_tipo_almacen.html', {'lista_tipo_almacen': lista_tipo_almacen, 'error': 'tu mensaje',}), y recuperas el mensaje en el template.

Comment: Hola @AndresVilca si esta o cualquier otra respuesta ha resuelto su problema, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) clicando la marca de check (en forma de V debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta). Esto indica a la comunidad que has encontrado una solución y de paso os dará reputación a ambos (a tí y quien ha respondido). Por supuesto, no tienes ninguna obligación de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es incluir la paginacion prueba asi:

view.py

```
class ListarTipoAlmacen(ListView):
    model = Tipo_almacen
    template_name = 'tipo_almacen/lista_tipo_almacen.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    errores = []
    if request.method == 'GET':
        buscar_descripcion = request.GET.get('buscar_descripcion', '')
        if not request.GET.get('buscar_descripcion', ''):
            errores.append('Ingrese dato por favor')
        else:
            lista_tipo_almacen = Tipo_almacen.objects.filter(descripcion__icontains=buscar_descripcion)

            paginator = Paginator(lista_tipo_almacen, 10)

            parametros = request.GET.copy()
            if parametros.has_key('pagina'):
                del parametros['pagina']

            page = request.GET.get('pagina')
            try:
                queryset = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:

                queryset = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:

                queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

            context = {
                "objetc_list": queryset,
                "parametros": parametros,
            }
            return render(request, 'tipo_almacen/lista_tipo_almacen.html', context)
    return render(request, 'tipo_almacen/lista_tipo_almacen.html', {'errores': errores})
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
      {% if errores %}

          {% for error in errores %}
            <h5>{{ error }}</h5>
          {% endfor %}

      {% endif %}

    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <input id="textinput" name="textinput" placeholder="ingrese nombre" class="form-control input-md" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>

 {% if objetc_list %}
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4>Lista de Tipo de almacen</h4>
    </div>

    <table class="table">
        <th>Nombres</th>
        <th>Editar</th>
        <th>Borrar</th>
        <tbody>
            {% for obj in objetc_list %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{obj.descripcion}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'editar_tipo_almacen' obj.pk %}">Editar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'eliminar-tipo-almacen' obj.pk %}" data-toggle="modal_almacen" data-target="#modal_almacen" data-id="{{ obj.descripcion }}">Eliminar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

  <ul class="pagination">
    {% if objetc_list.has_previous %}
      <li class="waves-effect"><a href="?pagina={{ objetc_list.previous_page_number }}{% if parametros.urlencode %}&{{ parametros.urlencode }}{% endif %}"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>
      {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i></a></li>
    {% endif %}

    {% for num in objetc_list.paginator.page_range %}
      {% ifequal num objetc_list.number %}
        <li class="active"><a href="#!">{{ num }}</a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="waves-effect"><a href="?pagina={{ num }}{% if parametros.urlencode %}&{{ parametros.urlencode }}{% endif %}">{{ num }}</a></li>
      {% endifequal %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if objetc_list.has_next %}
      <li class="waves-effect"><a href="?pagina={{ objetc_list.next_page_number }}{% if parametros.urlencode %}&{{ parametros.urlencode }}{% endif %}"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a></li>
      {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">chevron_right</i></a></li>
    {% endif %}
  </ul> 

{% else %} 

<p>El dato ingresado no existe</p>  

{% endif %} 

</div>
```